# how to use reg-exp to fetch the string which starts with $ symbol?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have tried with below query,

```
SELECT registration_line1 FROM table WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(column, '[$]+');
```

here I have used the above query to pull the records which stars with $, but its giving records irrespective of starts position? for example, its giving below result

```
$shankar
shank$ ar
but i need only
$shankar
```

please help how to get the result!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepend `^` to denote `at the beginning of the input`. `+` is not needed.

```
SELECT registration_line1 FROM table WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(column, '^[$]');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [LIKE](http://psoug.org/definition/LIKE.htm) instead of regex:

```
SELECT registration_line1 FROM table WHERE column LIKE '$%';
```

`%` means match any character(s).

Answer (score 0):

To match the beginning of the string, use the anchor `^`:

```
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(column, '^[$]')
```

You also don't need `+` if you just want to check if the first character is `$`.